# jquery input field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate user input data using jquery.
Here is the code I  use.

```
$('#ole').keypress(function(event) {
              if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            });
```

The code above allows only integers and a single dot. What I need is to allow only two integers after the dot.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY with this

#### HTML

```
<input id="ole" class="decimal">​
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).on('change blur','.decimal',function() {
      var amt = parseFloat(this.value);
      if(isNaN(amt)) {
        $(this).val('');
      }
      else {
         $(this).val(amt.toFixed(2));
      }
    });
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xxGdd/)
​

Comment: Only problem here is user may not expect automatic rounding, which might lead to input errors.  In fact, if this is a "money" field, then any digits to the right of the penny are probably accidental.  Nevertheless, +1 for the idea.

Comment: @AlexMa yes your are right, but rounding after 2 place look fine even in money format. isn't it so?

Comment: Thanks. Can you advice me how to combine your code with that I provide ?

Comment: write this code under `<script>` tag and add class `.alnum` on `<input>` tag. *Note:* use `jquery 1.7`

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regex expression and round the decimals:

```
$('#ole').on('blur', function()
{
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val.match(/^\d+\.{0,1}\d+$/)) 
    {
        // Convert to int if needed
        val = parseInt(val);

        val = Math.round(val *100)/100; // Round to 2 decimals
        $(this).val(val);
    }
});​
```